# Change array of SUMIF in case criteria exists in two different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
       A             B            C             D              E             F            
1  Results                      List A                      List B
2  Campaign       Sales         Campaign      Sales         Campaign        Sales
3  Campaign_A     1.510         Campaign_A     500          Campaign_B       50       
4  Campaign_B       120         Campaign_A     450          Campaign_B       40
5  Campaign_C        90         Campaign_A     560          Campaign_B       30
6  Campaign_D     1.650         Campaign_B     700          Campaign_C       80
7  Campaign_E       100         Campaign_B     710          Campaign_C       10
8  Campaing_F        70         Campaign_C     200          Campaign_F       70
9                               Campaing_D     850
10                              Campaing_D     800
11                              Campaing_E     100
12                              Campaing_F     320
13                              Campaing_F     360
14                              Campaing_F     290
15 
16
```

The `Excel table` above consists of:

```
List A = Column C:D
List B = Column E:F
```

In each list campaigns can appear mutliple times.

---

In `Column A:B` I want to `sum up` the `sales per campaign` from the two lists using the `SUMIF` formula:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,A3,D:D)
=SUMIF(E:E,A3,F:F)
```

However, the `List B` should be **prioritized** over `List A` which means in case a campaign exists in `List B (Column E)` the `SUMIF` function should be only applied to `List B` and `List A` should be totally ignored. 
The formula might look something like htis:

```
IF campaign exists in Column E then SUMIF(E:E,A3,F:F) else SUMIF(C:C,A3,D:D)
```

How can I achieve the desired results in `Column B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E:E,A3)>0,SUMIF(E:E,A3,F:F),SUMIF(C:C,A3,D:D))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the following:
    if(sumIf(E:E,A3,F:F)>0;sumIf(E:E,A3,F:F);sumIf(C:C,A3,D:D))